# flexbox items expand to full height

Tags: html, height, flexbox

I have a flexbox parent set for rows with 2 children.  I would like each child to fill to 100% of the height.  No matter what I try the children expand to the exact same height, which is the child/div with the tallest content.

How can I tell the children to fill to all available height? (or is this not possible)

My goal is to make the text in the left child appear at the top of the item, and text in the right child to appear at the bottom of the item.  But when both items are not tall, the effect doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `align-self` on the children to make them float to the top or bottom of the parent container:

[image]

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#parent{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  width:400px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid green;
}
#top{align-self:flex-start; border:1px solid red;min-width:100px;}
#bottom{align-self:flex-end; border: 1px solid blue;}
```

```html
<div id=parent>
  <div id='top'>Hi, I have a small bit of text.</div>
  <div id='bottom'>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged</div>
</div>
```